# How to install OpenSSH on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh

So I've been trying to install an ssh server on my local machine back home for ages, I tried to ask here yesterday and so far I haven't got any results. I'm a programmer, I have a PC (the server) in our house which contains my projects, and since I can't bring it anywhere I go, I decided to install and SSH/SFTP server on it to make me compile my projects anywhere.

I installed openssh, using this guide (https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH) except for step 7.

Now I am stuck on: how do I configure it to so that I could login on it? say, on my client ssh program like connectbot (android) I could it like this myusername@remotehostIP?

I'm basically new to this matter and really need some help, thank you.

Comment: Do you want OpenSSH specifically or just a SSH server in general?

Comment: What version of Windows + Your question is pretty unclear. You didn't really tell us what problem are you facing.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure why you're using that Wiki article.  Nor am I sure if OpenSSH (circa 2004) is necessarily the best choice for your particular use case.

Nevertheless - you should be able to:

1. Download from here:

   https://sourceforge.net/projects/sshwindows/files/latest/download
2. Simply extract the .zip and run the .msi.

=================================================================

ADDENDUM:

I originally thought you were having problems with the "install".  If there's any doubt in your mind, please (re)visit:

- The [original OpenSSH Project](https://www.openssh.com/) page, last updated October 19, 2018

  as well as
- The [new Microsoft OpenSSH port](https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable).

But I'm also wondering if OpenSSH is really the best solution for your use case?

Q: Are you running Windows on your server?  Q: Do you want/need Windows GUI access?

If so, perhaps you want to consider a VPN (for secure access).

For example:

https://www.comparitech.com/blog/vpn-privacy/best-vpn-for-windows-10/

Comment: Well, *you're* the one suggesting a 2004 build, but OP is trying to use Microsoft's official OpenSSH v7.7 build that was released just earlier this year (July 2018). There's more than one port in existence...